# window.onscroll is not firing in a page with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have javascript file that has onscroll event handler. When a webpage includes this javascript file, and when the page gets scrolled event handler gets called and it does the required work on scroll.

It is working fine and many web pages work successfully. But, today one webpage that uses AngularJS framework included my javascript file, window.onscroll handler is not getting called.

Could anyone suggest how to handle Angular pages without breaking existing ones? Thank you so much.

Javascript file structure is like this

```
(function() {
    window.onscroll = function() {
        /* on scroll work logic */
    }
})(this);
```

What change can I suggest to page owner so that their angular app can somehow let window.onscroll method in my javascript file to execute during page scroll?

please note that I don't own angular app. I own simple javascript file with window.onscroll handler.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `$window` replica of `window` object. `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window`. However, i don't think using `window` will cause any issue in angular js. Any errors ?

Comment: maybe the window is not scrollable and the callback is not fired consequently

Comment: I see `<body layout-xs="row" ng-app="AnnualReport" ontouchstart="hideScroll()" ontouchmove="hideScroll()" class="ng-scope layout-xs-row">` on the problematic page. I am not sure what they mean. Page has scroll vertical bar visible.

Comment: Also, there are no errors in console.log

Comment: what's inside hideScroll() function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $window replica of window object

```
app = angular.module('exampleApp', []);
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
          //code
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Can I use above even when I don't own the angular app? I tried your code but nothing happened.